# Bootstrapper not installing and returns with an error

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I am new to wix and I am working on a bootstrapper application which installs prerequisites which are required to install my software. Sql Server 2014 is one of the prerequisites. When the bootstrapper runs it fails with an error  0x851a0012. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong.

```
 <?define SqlInstanceName=MySqlInstance?>
 <?define SqlInstallCommand=/ACTION=Install /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlInstanceName) /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /SECURITYMODE=SQL ?>
<?define SqlUninstallCommand=/ACTION=Uninstall /Q /FEATURES=SQLEngine /INSTANCENAME=$(var.SqlInstanceName) ?>
```

```
    <Fragment>
    <!-- TODO: Put your code here.-->
<util:RegistrySearch Id="regsearchSqlInstanceFound"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
                    Value="$(var.SqlInstanceName)"
                    Result="exists"
                    Variable="SqlInstanceFound"/>
<PackageGroup Id="SqlServerPackageGroup">
  <ExePackage SourceFile="SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
              DetectCondition="SqlInstanceFound"
              InstallCommand="$(var.SqlInstallCommand)"
              UninstallCommand="$(var.SqlUninstallCommand)"
              RepairCommand="$(var.SqlRepairCommand)" />
</PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

This is a test Project wanted to implement Sql Server First get it running and then include my msi package in the bootstrapper.

Comment: Is there any error description in the log? Id there is no description its most probably an error from the exe so you should check the SQL Server exe log (I think it's supposed to be at: %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\" but i'm not sure)

Comment: @TeaHoney after uninstalling the sql server 2014 I did a restart and then tried running my bootstrapper it worked.